# Anaconda не видит пакеты установленные pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Я устанавливаю пакеты с помощью pip, но Anaconda их не видит. Работаю на ubuntu. Нашел похожий вопрос в англоязычной версии, оттуда узнал, что есть конфликт с системный pip и из репозитория Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

Сonda -- это альтернатива как к apt-get/yum/homebrew так и иногда к pip, поставляемому с Ubuntu или python.org сборкой. Conda это кросс-платформенный package manager. Особенно полезен на Windows, для людей без настроенного компилятора (до широкого распространения binary wheels) и для управления не-python зависимостями. [Conda: Myths and Misconceptions](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/).

Если вы используете Anaconda, то сперва следует попробовать установить пакет, используя `conda install`, и только если в доступных conda репозиториях нет желаемой версии такого пакета, тогда можно установить с помощью версии pip, установленной в [текущее conda окружение](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#verify-current-environment):

```
$ conda install pip
$ pip install oo  # requires pygame
$ python -moo
```

Сonda в том числе [позволяет разные версии самого python установить](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html). Разные conda окружения могут использовать разные версии python/pip.

Comment: тут дело не в этом

Comment: @lion12 что вы имеете ввиду? Вы попробовали команды из ответа и получили что?

Answer (score 0):

`conda` и `pip` два инструмента, которые не взаимодействуют друг с другом. 
`Conda` нацелен на то, чтобы делать больше, чем `pip`; обрабатывать зависимости библиотек за пределами пакетов `Python`, а также сами пакеты `Python`. Conda также создает виртуальную среду, например `virtualenv`.
Поскольку `Conda` вводит новый формат упаковки, вы не можете использовать `pip` и `Conda` взаимозаменяемо; `pip` не может установить формат пакета `Conda`. Вы можете использовать два инструмента бок о бок (путем установки `pip` с помощью `conda install pip`), но они также не взаимодействуют.

Используйте эти инструменты с умом. Поставьте пакеты которые вам требуются и используйте их на `Python`. Описанная вами проблема, на мой взгляд, не важна и не достойна рассмотрения.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы пакеты, установленные pip, были видны в Python Анаконды используйте тот pip, который находится в папке bin Анаконды.

Answer (score -1):

В IDE

`File ---> Settings... ---> %projectname% ---> Project Interpretier.` Там на плюсик и качаешь. 
Ведь анаконда это PyCharm, верно?

Comment: "Ведь анаконда это PyCharm, верно?" - неверно